# How to restart an AsyncTask or avoid if RUNNING

Tags: java, android

I am Developing an App that parses data from HTML. One of the data that is parsed is an integer that increases over time and rather than constantly requesting the data I would like to have a task that intervals the integer. Due to the fact that I need the value updated into a TextView I decided to go with an AsyncTask rather than a Timer.

My issue is I want to be able to restart my task once I know that it has finished, or if it is currently RUNNING simply avoid manipulating it.

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
class TurnsUpdate extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Exception>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        turns = Integer.parseInt(DATABASE.getValue("turns").replaceAll(" T", ""));
    }

    protected Exception doInBackground(Void...voids)
    {
        while (turns < maxTurns)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                return e;
            }

            turns++;
            publishProgress(turns);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... turns)
    {
        infoTurns.setText(Integer.toString(turns[0]) + " T");
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Exception e)
    {
        vibrator.vibrate(500);
    }
}
```

My attempt to start or avoid:

```
  if ((HOME.updateTurns == null || HOME.updateTurns.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) && HOME.updateTurns.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
    {
        HOME.updateTurns = (UpdateTurns) new UpdateTurns();
        HOME.updateTurns.execute();
    }
```

Am I going about this correctly?

Comment: I worked around the issue by making TurnsUpdate it's own public class and making the infoTurns a protected reference. It all works as far as I can tell for now.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I am still having an issue with restarting the AsyncTask after it is FINISHED or avoiding it if it is RUNNING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just making a recursive call:

```
new UpdateTurns().execute()
```

in onPostExecute? Technically it should work since any code in onPostExecute is run on the UI thread as opposed to the thread created in AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting an exception when trying to call .execute() on an AsyncTask with a status of FINISHED. I finally found this line in the API:

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html under 'Threading Rules'

Comment: It's been awhile since I worked on this project but if I remember correctly I always created a new AsyncTask which avoids having this issue.